# If statement in for loop not filtering out items in solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

```
// @param physicalAddress - the actual address of the home a host wants to list (not the ethereum address)
// @return _id - list of ids for homes
function listHomesByAddress(string _physicalAddress) public returns(uint [] _id ) {
    uint [] results;
    for(uint i = 0 ; i<homes.length; i++) {
        if(keccak256(homes[i].physicalAddress) == keccak256(_physicalAddress) && homes[i].available == true) {
            results.push(homes[i].id);
        }
    }
    return results;    
}
```

The result is supposed to be a list of ids which match the physical address entered however it does not filter through but returns all the available homes.
When I change to using String utils nothing changes.

Here is the whole code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "browser/StringUtils.sol";

// @title HomeListing

contract HomeListing {

    struct Home {
        uint id;
        string physicalAddress;
        bool available;
    }

    Home[] public homes;
    mapping (address => Home) hostToHome;
    event HomeEvent(uint _id);
    event Test(uint length);

    constructor() {

    }

    // @param physicalAddress - the actual address of the home a host wants to list (not the ethereum address)
    function addHome(string _physicalAddress) public {
        uint _id = uint(keccak256(_physicalAddress, msg.sender));
        homes.push(Home(_id, _physicalAddress, true));
    }

    // @param physicalAddress - the actual address of the home a host wants to list (not the ethereum address)
    // @return _id - list of ids for homes
    function listHomesByAddress(string _physicalAddress) public returns(uint [] _id ) {
        uint [] results;
        for(uint i = 0 ; i<homes.length; i++) {
            string location = homes[i].physicalAddress;
            if(StringUtils.equal(location,_physicalAddress )) {
                results.push(homes[i].id);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part giving you trouble is the line `uint[] results;`. Arrays declared as local variables reference `storage` memory by default. From the "What is the memory keyword" section of the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do):

> There are defaults for the storage location depending on which type of variable it concerns:
>
> - state variables are always in storage
> - function arguments are in memory by default
> - **local variables of struct, array or mapping type reference storage by default**
> - local variables of value type (i.e. neither array, nor struct nor mapping) are stored in the stack

The result is you're referencing the first storage slot of your contract, which happens to be `Home[] public homes`. That's why you're getting the entire array back.

To fix the problem, you need to use a `memory` array. However, you have an additional problem in that you can't use dynamic memory arrays in Solidity. A workaround is to decide on a result size limit and declare your array statically.

Example (limited to 10 results):

```
function listHomesByAddress(string _physicalAddress) public view returns(uint[10]) {
    uint [10] memory results;
    uint j = 0;
    for(uint i = 0 ; i<homes.length && j < 10; i++) {
        if(keccak256(homes[i].physicalAddress) == keccak256(_physicalAddress) && homes[i].available == true) {
            results[j++] = homes[i].id;
        }
    }
    return results;

}
```